# Merger Array Table

Tags: php

I have two array, I would like to merge them without duplicating in "name",

```html
$array1[]= array(name['udi','ari'],id['1','2'])
$array2[]= array(name['udi','ari'],age['22','18'])
```

result

```html
$arrayresult[]= array(name['udi','ari'],id['1','2'],age['22','18'])
```

Comment: Is `name['udi','ari']` a string or `name => ['udi','ari']` short array syntax?

Comment: u have id in ist array and age in second right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for merging both array as:

**Example:**

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
            'name'=>array('udi','ari'),
            'id'=>array('1','2'),
            );

$array2 = array(
            'name'=>array('udi','ari'),
            'age'=>array('22','18'),
            );

$newArr = array_merge($array1,$array2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => udi
            [1] => ari
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 18
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is array_merge:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$arrayresult =  array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

should give you:

```
$arrayresult = array(name('udi','ari'),id('1','2'),age('22','18'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use first `$result=array_merge($array1,$array2)` and then use `$result=array_unique($result)` its remove duplicate value.